# Is it possible to take full screenshots of a webpage via actionscript 3.0?

Tags: actionscript-3, screenshot

Here's the catch,I need to take a full screenshot of a webpage via actionscript, I know this is possible on other programming languages (like PHP & CutyCapt), but via actionscript, is there a way to accomplish it?

The full screenshot should be able to take the entire webpage which might include swfs / videos.

Please note, im only interested for available solutions (if any!) for Actionscript, not references to libraries / other programming languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. This would be a huge security vulnerability. Imagine if some 3rd party Flash ad could randomly just screen capture anything that you are doing on the webpage (login details, personal information, activity etc.).

Anything within the SWF itself is fair game however.

I'd advise you to think about why you need the screenshot and from there try to find another approach that can give you the same effect as a screenshot, since it is impossible to take a screenshot of the whole webpage just from ActionScript.

Answer (score 2):

No way. You can take screenshot of current swf only.

Answer (score 0):

It seems possible today.

There is a "neat" (sarcasm) Flash advertisement running on Yahoo.com, which captures the current visual state of HTML elements on that page.   See the attached screenshot.   Items that are pure HTML, and have been interacted with by me just prior to the advertisement capturing an image, are part of that image, which it then applies an effect to.  You can tell when the swf captures focus.   It isn't performing a server-side operation or even simulating the capture.  Looks real to me; however, I'll concede that I haven't looked at the latest player's capabilities or security vulnerabilities in a few months.  If someone can explain how that is NOT a capture I'd be intere

I do agree that this is a huge security vulnerability.   Can you imagine the possibilities?  Many bank sites allow Flash advertisements to run on them.  It wouldn't take much more effort to capture account balances and transaction details.

[image]